# Distribute operator

Tags: operators

I have an operator defined by `\[ScriptCapitalN]` and want to `Expand` a term and then use `Distribute` in order to apply the operator `\[ScriptCapitalN]` to every term individually. However,

```
Distribute[
 Map[Expand, 
  1/(1 + x) \[ScriptCapitalN][(DiracDelta[om - om1 - om2 - om3] f[
         om1] + DiracDelta[om - om1 - om2 - om3] f[om2])/(4 om)], 
  Infinity]]
```

doesn't seem to work.

[Edit]

The desired output is supposed to be

```
\[ScriptCapitalN][(DiracDelta[om - om1 - om2 - om3] f[om1])/(4 om)]/(
 1 + x) + \[ScriptCapitalN][(
  DiracDelta[om - om1 - om2 - om3] f[om2])/(4 om)]/(1 + x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's indeed a bit annoying. Try to use `MapAll`; this will `Distribute` at every level:

```
exp = Map[Expand, 
  1/(1 + x) \[ScriptCapitalN][(DiracDelta[om - om1 - om2 - om3] f[
         om1] + DiracDelta[om - om1 - om2 - om3] f[om2])/(4 om)],
  ∞
  ]
MapAll[Distribute[#, Plus, \[ScriptCapitalN]] &, exp]
```

A probably faster alternative for complex expression would be to use `ReplaceAll` (`/.`):

```
exp /. x_\[ScriptCapitalN] :> Distribute[x, Plus, \[ScriptCapitalN]]
```

Maybe `ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`) is needed for deeply nested expression.

Comment: Yeah, I was experimenting with `MapAll` as well but should have used the pure function in your code (otherwise also the `DiracDelta` will be distributed since you cannot specify the options in `Distribute`). Wrapping around a `Apart` at the very end does the intended job. Thank you for your help!

Comment: It certainly takes a long time now for the actual term where I want to use it. More than two minutes for 344 separated terms in the end. The time consumption might be an issue because I need to apply the procedure to a term which contains even more subexpression in the end (order of magnitude more).

Comment: You're welcome. Please try also the new approach added. Maybe it is faster.

Comment: It is indeed faster. Do you know by chance a way to reverse the action of distribute? A similar function like `Together` but for operators, such that in the end, one has wrapped again `\[ScriptCapitalN]` around the different subexpressions?

Comment: Try `exp2 //. Plus[x_\[ScriptCapitalN], 
   y_\[ScriptCapitalN]] :> \[ScriptCapitalN][Plus[x[[1]], y[[1]]]]`.

Comment: This works only if I don't apply `Apart` after distributing the N-operator. Probably because the levelspec in the pattern is then no longer correct?

Comment: Then you have to let the fractions come `Together`, first.

Comment: Ok thx, I should look more into pattern matching :)

Comment: Yes, indeed. ;) You're welcome. Btw.: It is often helpful to apply `FullForm` to the expression to modify.

Comment: Yeah, I read about that. I am currently reading `The Mathematica Book` which is kind of old but still helpful to my mind. Though it needs a lot of time to read it completely, unfortunately.

Comment: Mhh, I still have trouble with some prefactors in the numerator to re-combine it together. A simple `Together` seems only to work if there is a denominator. It's a pity that there is no built-in function. Ok but then I should use `FullForm` indeed.

Comment: Honestly, I learned the most that I know now from from this site, from trial and error, and from the documentation (roughly in that order of importance). Getting the basic principles of the languange from the book is just fine, but I doubt you have to read everything.

Comment: Maybe this works better: `exp2 = \[Alpha] \[ScriptCapitalN][a] + \[Beta] \[ScriptCapitalN][b];
exp2 //. Plus[Times[\[Alpha]_ x_\[ScriptCapitalN]], 
   Times[\[Beta]_, y_\[ScriptCapitalN]]] :> \[ScriptCapitalN][
   Plus[\[Alpha] x[[1]], \[Beta] y[[1]]]]`; the inverse rule should also serve as substitute for `Distribute`.

Comment: It seems like `a \[ScriptCapitalN][x] + b \[ScriptCapitalN][y] //. 
 Plus[a__ x_\[ScriptCapitalN], 
   b__ y_\[ScriptCapitalN]] :> \[ScriptCapitalN][
   Plus[a x[[1]], b y[[1]]]]` is doing what I need. But only for two summands mhh.

Comment: Try also this: `exp2 = \[Alpha] \[ScriptCapitalN][a] + \[Beta] \[ScriptCapitalN][
     b] + \[ScriptCapitalN][c];
exp2 //. {Times[\[Alpha]___, 
     x_\[ScriptCapitalN]] :> \[ScriptCapitalN][\[Alpha] x[[
       1]]]} //. {
  Plus[ x_\[ScriptCapitalN], 
    y_\[ScriptCapitalN]] :> \[ScriptCapitalN][Plus[x[[1]], y[[1]]]]
  }`. It treats also factors of `1` (which disappear) correctly.

Comment: Yes you're right, trial and error can be daunting but probably it's the best way. Also in this way you apply it to `real` problems and not just these exemplary examples in the books.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82962/discussion-between-henrik-schumacher-and-display-name).